# How to Total up NULL results from JOIN Query

Tags: sql

I have written a left Join Query that returns all NULLS.

```
SELECT JourneyID,`TrainSeatID`, PassengerID FROM `TrainSeating` 
LEFT JOIN Passenger ON TrainSeating.TrainSeatID = Passenger.PassTrainSeatID
WHERE PassengerID IS NULL;
```

Does anyone know how I can total up these NULLS and include the total number in the data set?

EDIT: I want to calculate the amount of NULL returns from a specific JourneyID.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT()` to get the number of rows in `TrainSeating` that have not passengers:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TrainSeating LEFT JOIN
     Passenger
     ON TrainSeating.TrainSeatID = Passenger.PassTrainSeatID
WHERE PassengerID IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

If you want this per `JourneyId` then aggregate

```
SELECT ts.JourneyId, COUNT(*)
FROM TrainSeating ts LEFT JOIN
     Passenger p
     ON ts.TrainSeatID = p.PassTrainSeatID
WHERE p.PassengerID IS NULL
GROUP BY ts.JourneyId
```